# Difference between шоссе and автострада?

Tags: словоупотребление, лексикон

What are the differences between these two words? Is автострада just the same thing, but less used? Or do they have different meanings?

Comment: Colloquially, you can use "шоссе" instead of "автострада", but not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Шоссе is a paved highway outside of built-up areas or generally any paved road with several lanes outside a city

Автострада is a controlled-access highway that doesn't have single-level interchanges or crossings with other roads.

Moreover, there is also магистраль (автомагистраль) for arterial thoroughfare in urban areas or road that connects two or more urban areas.

Comment: There are plenty of шоссе in cities. In Moscow particularly. But I'll admit that historically they weren't.

Comment: According to Ozhegov a road with a crushed stone surface is also шоссе. An example would be the road along which Шурик walks in the first few minutes of Кавкаская пленница. In fact, at about the five minute mark he calls it шоссе.

Answer (score 4):

*Шоссе* is a major atrterial road, whether in a city or (more typical) between cities. Equivalent to *highway*.

*Автострада* is a slightly dated word (was more popular in the 60-70s) of Italian origin for what is officially known as автомагистраль. Equivalent to *freeway* or *motorway*.

That said, colloquially it is common to use шоссе generically for any major road, even if it's formally an автомагистраль. Perhaps because it's a shorter word.

Answer (score 0):

Шоссе is a standard road, a highway that goes to a large settlement.
According to traffic rules the speed limit is 90km/h.

Автострада is a road of better quality. Now this word is not widely used.

Автомагистраль is a highway of best quality. It is considered differently in traffic rules. The speed limit is 110km/h or even more, no stops are allowed, no bikes, no horses :)

Comment: Шоссе is marked with blue road signs. Автомагистраль is marked with green road signs.